# uniqueness of split idempotent

Tags: category-theory, idempotents

In a category, if an idempotent $f:a \longrightarrow a$ splits, then any two splittings are isomorphic.
Let $i: b \longrightarrow a$ and $p: a \longrightarrow b$ be such that $i\circ p=f$ and $p\circ i=id_b$ and also
$j:c \longrightarrow a$ and $q: a\longrightarrow c$ be such that $j\circ q=f$ and $q\circ j=id_c$.
Then $b$ is isomorphic to $c$. What is the isomorphism between $b$ and $c$?

Comment: A different way to see this is the following. If $e = sr$ is a splitting of the idempotent $e$, then $rs = 1$, so in particular $s$ is a section of $r$. It is not hard to show that $s$ is the equalizer of $1$ and $sr  = e$ and $r$ is the coequalizer of $e$ and $1$. Thus $s$ and $r$ have universal properties with respect to the pair $(1,e)$, which makes them unique up to unique isomorphisms.

Answer (score 6):

There is only one distinguished morphism $b \to c$, namely $qi$, and the same for $c \to b$, namely $pj$. One checks without effort that they are inverse to each other. For example, we have $qi \, pj = qfj = qjqj=1$.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin said: The morphism $g=qi:b\to c$ is the inverse of $h=pj:c\to b$.
I'd like to add a different approach:
We see that $p\circ 1_a=1_bp=(pi)p=p(ip)=p\circ f$ is a cocone over the diagram $a\xrightarrow{1}a\xrightarrow{f}a$.
Now let's assume that $q:a\to c$ is another cocone (we don't need the $j$ for now). Then $g=qi:b\to c$ is an arrow such that $gp=qip=qf=q1_a=q$, so $g$ is a morphism between cocones. Since $p$ is epic, it is the only such morphism, which means that $p:a\to b$ is the colimit of the diagram $a\xrightarrow{1}a\xrightarrow{f}a$.
If we assume the existence of a $j$ as in your question, then $c$ is another colimit, so there must be an isomorphism $b\simeq c$.

Also note that since $p^\text{op}i^\text{op}=f^\text{op}$, $\ i^\text{op}p^\text{op}=1_b$, and $f^\text{op}f^\text{op}=f^\text{op}$, it follows dually that $i:b\to a$ is the limit of the diagram.